# Ajax call div replace and scroll to top of the page

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, scroll

There is an ajax call for Details button. It loads a html content to div id="comDetails" and hide the  div id="allcomm"
But it remains the scroll bar at the same position. I want to go to top of the page after loading the content to   div id="comDetails"

```
<div id="comDetails">

</div>

<div id="allcomm">
  <a  onclick="loadDetails('@card.Guid')">Details</a>
</div>
```

Ajax call
    function loadDetails(guid) {

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Center/Com/Detail",
    data: { cardGuid: guid },
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
    success: function (data) {            

        $("#allcomm").hide();
        $("#comDetails").show();

        $("#comDetails").html(data);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest work-around, `add href="#"`;

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadDetails('@card.Guid')">Details</a>
```

Script solution;

```
success: function (data) {            
   $("#allcomm").hide();
   $("#comDetails").show();
   $("#comDetails").html(data);

   window.scrollTo(0,0); // javascript
   $(window).scrollTop(0); // jquery
}
```